# How to Uninstall/Reinstall a custom module whithout losing the content?

Tags: 8

As we know : it's impossible to unsintall a module whithout being forced to remove all the data that's belongs to it.
The problem is, if we want to update a module we are obliged to uninstall it and then reinstall to get the changes work.

At developpement phase, it's ok , but what about being in a production site and having a big amount of data we don't want to loose, by just adding a field , or changing a type ....

Is there any best practises? Is there a process that could be advised? Is there any feedbacks of your own experience?

For example, I would guess : export data and then import data after the reinstall?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you obliged to uninstall a module to update it?

Comment: There is no case that you have to uninstall a module before update.... unless there is no upgrade path for the contrib module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make my changes take effect without removing all data -> uninstall -> reinstall the module .

Here the steps :

1. Make the changes (in my code , for exemple add a field in my entity class)
2. Add a [hook_update_N()](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/update-api/updating-database-schema-andor-data-in-drupal-8) in yourmodule.install (yourmodule is your module name)
   yourmodule.install is in the  root od your module, if not exist create it
3. Here the content of yourmodule.install

   `<?php
        /**
       * Document your changes 
        */
        function yourmodule_update_8001() {
       \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()->applyUpdates();
         }`
4. Execute update.php et the change take effect in the database !

NB: I made my changes in my custom module code using BaseFieldDefinition, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can update your database with

> hook_update_xx

if your module define hook_shema

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/update-api/updating-database-schema-andor-data-in-drupal-8

Comment: I had no idea of what are hooks :D , well I'll try, could give a links for drupal 8 tutorials. (I find tutorial for drupal 7 not 8 )